# Pygame background not blitting

Tags: python, pygame

I'm just learning GUI programming using python 3.2 and pygame 1.8. From what I understand the following code should display a white background. However all I get is a black screen. Also, I'm using IDLE in Windows 7 if that matters:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have a main loop that updates the screen. This code should work:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255, 255, 255))

while True:
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: i get this error now:
in line 11 screen.update()

AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: @Ahmed - I am assuming you mean in the comment, there is a help link just underneath the "Add Comment" button which explains [comment formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments/24794#24794).  For `code formatting` put the code inside of `\`backticks\``.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to update the screen.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't blit the backgound you just put the fill part in the loop. Also you are forgetting the `pygame.display.update()`